# Amplify Data model, Is this adding a many to 1 relationship. (typical child to parent relationship)?

Tags: aws-amplify, data-modeling

I think I know the answer but am I missing something here?

Below 3 screenshots shows the setup of a new parent relationship from a table called "MenuItem".
and this is me trying to setup a new relationship to its parent "Organisation".

I assume this one is correct, but it reads wrong in my opinion.
[image]

[image]

[image]

So my understanding is this would be a Many (MenuItems) : 1 (Organisation) relationship.

but that is not even an option on this screen.

Is One-to-One the option I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am going to preface this by saying I do not know GraphQL.
But what I do know is data model cardinality, and the above resulting data models were not as I expected.**

Also normally when building a relationship to a parent table you start on the child and create a field like "OrgId".

Well in Amplify it is the other way around, instead you start on the parent and choose a child table/object to build the relationship, and Amplify Studio creates the field ("orgID") on the child table/object for you (be careful this was recently broken and fixed (relationship naming was duplicated causing deployment errors).

So my previous understanding was entirely wrong within the Amplify Studio.

So the answer is :
**"NO", do not start building the relationship on the child object, go to the parent object and start there, and it will make much more sense (it just wont be technically logical from a purest perspective, so do not let that trouble you like it did me.**

And better yet, build it in the graphql.schema and >amplify push the schema.